# Need Help Solving a dealing with Atmospheric Pressure

Tags: functions

I am struggling with a physics problem that I hope some of you may be able to help me with. The problem involves atmospheric pressure and the question is:

"On Earth, the average air pressure at sea level is 1,013 hectopascals (hPa). The pressure decreases linearly up to 500 meters above sea level. At what altitude is the pressure 970 hPa? For every ten meters above sea level, the air pressure decreases by 1.23 per thousand of the pressure at sea level."

My attempt to solve this problem involved using the equation for the linear decrease in pressure with altitude, which is:

P = P0 - (k * h)

where P is the pressure at altitude h, P0 is the pressure at sea level, and k is the rate of decrease in pressure per unit altitude.

Using the information given in the problem, we have:

P0 = 1013 hPa
P = 970 hPa
k = 0.00123

Substituting these values into the equation, we get:

970 = 1013 - (0.00123 * h)

Solving for h, we get:

h = (1013 - 970) / 0.00123 = 34878.05 meters

However, this answer seems way too high and I'm not sure where I went wrong. I would really appreciate any help or guidance on how to approach this problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "For every ten meters above sea level, the air pressure decreases by 1.23 per thousand of the pressure at sea level" is confusing wording. I interpret this as $1.23 {1013 \over 1000} {1 \over 10} = 0.12460 $ mb/m. In the real world, pressure drops (very) approximately 0.1mb/m at sea level, so this is ballpark. Based on that I get $h={1013-970 \over 0.12460} = 345.11$ m. (Here is an online calculator https://www.mide.com/air-pressure-at-altitude-calculator.)

Comment: Why do we write 1.23 * 1013/1000? Where does the 1013 part come from?

Comment: 1013 is the sea level pressure.